# Storing Datatype Information

Tags: c++, typeinfo

Let's say I have a few variables of different types.

```
int MyInteger;
double MyDouble;
char MyChar;
```

Pointers to these variables are stored in a single array of void pointers.

```
void* IntegerPointer = &MyInteger;
void* DoublePointer = &MyDouble;
void* CharPointer = &MyChar;

void* PointerArray[] = {IntegerPointer, DoublePointer, CharPointer};
```

I'd like to store the datatype information in a parallel array.  `type_info` seems to be suited to the task, but assignment isn't supported.  So I can't just do something like this:

```
type_info TypeInfoArray[] = {int, double, char};
```

Is there any other way to store information about a datatype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use a variant type. I hate to say it, but try [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/variant.html) (or something similar). Forget all this parallel array and void pointer stuff; a single array of variants achieves the same thing and is more elegant.

Comment: Much more elegant, especially as you can store them by value, not by pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/). Then you can store type info as an array of std::string

Comment: I see how to get the decorated name of a datatype, but is there a way to convert it the other way to use to cast a void pointer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a container to hold a sequence of different types, look no further than [boost::fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html).

For example, if you use a fusion sequence for your types,

```
fusion::vector<int, double, char> object_array(1, 2.0, 'F');
```

Now, to get what's at index 0 for example

```
at<0>(object_array); // will provide a reference to the int field
```

It's perfectly type safe, and not a `void *` in sight... The only downside is that there is a limit to the number of "elements" you can have in the sequence (typically the number of template parameters as enforced by the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

A tuple would also do the job.

```
std::tuple<int*,float*> tp (&yourInt, &yourFloat);
```